# operations made to a numpy array inside a module affects variables outside of module

Tags: arrays, numpy, module

I'm having this issue and I'm not sure why is happening, and why it does not happen to all variables. 
I wrote an optimization algorithm for several parameters. 
example I have two multidimensional numpy arrays 
"parameters" is a 3 dimensional array and 
"lambda" a 2 dimensional array

I will summarize the code since is a few hundred lines long

```
parametersOpt,lambdaOpt=myOptModule(parameters,lambda)

def myOptModule(parameters,lambda):
    **Optimization code here**
     parameters=parameters-delta_parameters
     lambda=lambda-delta_lambda

    return parameters, lambda
```

what happens is that code is executed and for some reason the variable "parameters" changes and becomes the same as "parametersOpt" it changes automatically even tough the operations occur inside a module, and this is not the case to variable "lambda", lambda and lambdaOpt are not the same as it should be expected. Any ideas? I tries changing the names of variables inside and outside the module but that didn't work

Comment: You need to show the code where you wrote `**Optimization code here**`, because that's where the problem is occurring.  It would be much easier for someone to help you if you provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Try simplifying the "few hundred lines" as much as possible while still producing the problem.

Comment: It's possible that `optimization code` does something like `x = parameters`, and then goes on to modify `x`.  That assignment doesn't make a copy, so those modifications will appear in the original `parameters` object.  Reassigning `parameters` at the end doesn't change that.